# Why didn't Ravana's navy stop Rama when he was building the bridge over Indian Ocean?

Tags: movie, ramayana-legend-of-prince-rama

In 1992 cartoon film [Ramayana: The Legend of Prince Rama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana:_The_Legend_of_Prince_Rama), Rama needed to transport his troops across Indian Ocean to attack Ravana. Unfortunately, he didn't have airforce or navy. So, he built a bridge to transport his army.

But, why did Ravana allow this construction of bridge? Why didn't his navy or coast army intervene?

Comment: What sorts of sources are you willing to accept. If there's a mythological/scriptural reason, would that be acceptable?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No.

Comment: @CaptainMarvel  I haven’t watched it, but, is there any evidence in the movie that the Lankans had a Navy ?

Comment: @Shreedhar Hanuman had to face two big hurdles while crossing the ocean, one of which was a giant monster Sursa. Other than this, Lanka was a state surrounded by ocean, so it's safe to assume that it had navy (Ravana already had lots of monsters who could walk on water or fly). If not, coast army could definitely intervene.